# Add vertical space before a line

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, boxes

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper] {article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\begin{document}

\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Text of Certification}\\
\end{center}
I hereby confirm that the Bachelor Thesis presented by me has been prepared independently, using no other sources, resources and other aids than those mentioned. All parts - literally or by their meaning - taken from published or non-published sources are credited as such. The Bachelor Thesis in its current or similar form has never been submitted as a graded assignment.\\
\noindent\makebox[3cm]{\hrulefill} \hfill\makebox[3cm]{\hrulefill}\\
\noindent\makebox[3cm][l]{Date} \hfill\makebox[3cm][l]{Signature}\\
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage


\end{document}
```

That will produce the following output:

[image]

I want to drag down the drawn boxes for additional space for the actual signature and date. I tried using the `\vspace` command again, but encounter the following problem, with the code as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper] {article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\begin{document}

\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Text of Certification}\\
\end{center}
I hereby confirm that the Bachelor Thesis presented by me has been prepared independently, using no other sources, resources and other aids than those mentioned. All parts - literally or by their meaning - taken from published or non-published sources are credited as such. The Bachelor Thesis in its current or similar form has never been submitted as a graded assignment.\\
\vspace{2cm}
\noindent\makebox[3cm]{\hrulefill} \hfill\makebox[3cm]{\hrulefill}\\
\noindent\makebox[3cm][l]{Date} \hfill\makebox[3cm][l]{Signature}\\
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage


\end{document}
```

I produce the following output:

[image]

So I'm not sure why only the second line of makeboxes is dragged down. `\vspace*{2cm}` produces the same output. I surely would like to have the horizontal line further down as well.

Comment: @cfr *Before* the spacing command

Comment: @egreg ?? Why before?

Comment: @cfr: `\vspace` is also considered (or stored until) you are in vertical mode. Placing `\par` *after* `\vspace` just "doesn't sit right" even though the output may be the same.

Comment: @Werner It isn't that I don't believe you, but that's not a ***reason*** ;)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper] {article}

\begin{document}
  \vspace*{1cm}
  \begin{center}
    \textbf{Text of Certification}\\
  \end{center}
  I hereby confirm that the Bachelor Thesis presented by me has been prepared independently, using no other sources, resources and other aids than those mentioned. All parts - literally or by their meaning - taken from published or non-published sources are credited as such. The Bachelor Thesis in its current or similar form has never been submitted as a graded assignment.

  \vspace{2cm}

  \noindent\makebox[3cm]{\hrulefill} \hfill\makebox[3cm]{\hrulefill}

  \noindent\makebox[3cm][l]{Date} \hfill\makebox[3cm][l]{Signature}

  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image: space before lines]

Comment: There's a ``\\`` to be removed; it's always better if `\vspace` is *between* paragraphs; a blank line before it suffices. The reason lies precisely in what is happening to the OP.

Comment: @egreg Why, though? I tried to generate something strange by putting it afterwards, but couldn't come up with anything.

Comment: thanks @cfr. didn't know there's a difference between \\ and paragraphs, also wasn't aware of the necessary blank line.

Comment: @marinko Generally, you should avoid using `\\\ ` except in particular environments e.g. tables or the `center` environment, because it doesn't do everything which a new paragraph should do.